# How to give a query a list of objects or items?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

my Question is that how can i give a list of objects or items to a  query :

for example i have an objects which has 4 user id like this :

`list_of_user_id = [1 , 2 ,3 ,6]` 

and now i want to set the `CreatorUserID` equal to `list_of_user_id`  to check how many of the users in `list_of_user_id`  exist in the `TblAnswerQuestionRequest` table .

this is my **Model.py :**

```
class TblAnswerQuestionRequest(models.Model):

    text = TextField(verbose_name='محتویات درخواست',max_length=4000, blank=True, null=True)
    CreatorUserID = models.ForeignKey(Members, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    knowledge_request = models.ForeignKey(TblQuestionRequest, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    CreateDate = IntegerField('تاریخ ثبت', default=LibAPADateTime.get_persian_date_normalized(), null=True, blank=True)
    create_hour = models.TimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(), null=True, blank=True)
    Status = IntegerField('وضعیت', default=1,choices=StatusChoices, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

and what i want is like this :

`Question_Users = TblAnswerQuestionRequest.objects.filter(CreatorUserID = list_of_user_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `__in` - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#in

```
Question_Users = TblAnswerQuestionRequest.objects.filter(CreatorUserID_id__in = list_of_user_id)
```

A small note, if you look at the database table from your model, you'll see that the column for the foreign key for `CreatorUserID` is going to actually be `CreatorUserID_id` (or possibly `creatoruserid_id`, not exactly sure how it treats uppercase letters in column names). So the `ID` in the foreign key name is bit obsolete, you probably want to only do `CreatorUser` or even better `creator_user`, so the column name then is `creator_user_id`.